# "Having" in SQL

Tags: sql, having, having-clause

I have a SQL like this below

```
SELECT A.UNIT, A.PO_NO, A.LINE, A.QUNATITY, 
       SUM(B.RECEIVED_QUNATITY) AS "RECEIVED QUANTITY" 
FROM PO_TBL A, RECEIVER_TBL B 
WHERE A.UNIT = B.UNIT AND A.PO_NO = B.PO_NO AND A.LINE = B.LINE 
GROUP BY A.UNIT, A.PO_NO, A.LINE, A.QUNATITY 
HAVING ((A.QUNATITY - SUM(B.RECEIVED_QUNATITY)) > 0);
```

The above SQL return more rows if the `Having` function is not used and returns null rows, when we using `Having`  function. Even though, Quantity has value as "10" and `RECEIVED_QUNATITY` has value as "0", that rows are not shown in the output. 
Kindly help me on this scenario......

Comment: Are you sure that the HAVING-condition has a match? Without knowing the data one can not decide your question.

Comment: You need to give the table structure with some sample data. Best would be to use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to recreate the source table so we know what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
I just place `isnull` function to check `null` values.

```
SELECT A.UNIT, A.PO_NO, A.LINE, A.QUNATITY, 
       SUM(B.RECEIVED_QUNATITY) AS "RECEIVED QUANTITY" 
FROM PO_TBL A, RECEIVER_TBL B 
WHERE A.UNIT = B.UNIT AND A.PO_NO = B.PO_NO AND A.LINE = B.LINE 
GROUP BY A.UNIT, A.PO_NO, A.LINE, A.QUNATITY 
HAVING ((A.QUNATITY - isnull(SUM(B.RECEIVED_QUNATITY),0)) > 0);
```

Assuming `A.Quantity` doesn't have null values or else implement `isnull` over it also.

Comment: Appreciate you thinking on a solution and giving the answer, but it is moot to answer a question if OP doesn't give complete information. For example `isnull` is not ANSI standard. It doesn't work in Oracle for sure. You can use `coalesce` or some function like that but we will never know until OP gives more information.

Comment: Hi Bhanu.... Thanks for help.... I used the below code to achieve what i needed. HAVING ((A.QUANTITY - (SUM(B.RECEIVED_QUANTITY)) IS NULL) OR (A.QUANTITY - (SUM(B.RECEIVED_QUANTITY)) <> 0))